# How to: FTP access to add-on domains in a hosted setup

Tags: symlink, hosted

I have a business grade hosting account with Webmasters.  The web server is Apache.  From time to time I setup what Wembasters call Add-on domains.

My problem is that I can't give Add-On domain users ftp access to their own web site.  Is there a way I can do this with symlinks or some such?

Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably have to ask Webmasters to get a real answer.  However, I will say this: these days, typically FTP servers (especially on shared hosts) jail the user to a specific directory and its subdirectories, and it's not possible to symlink out of that directory in almost all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, checked with Webmasters.  The ftp accounts are jailed to a specific directory.